# dispatchmessage function didn't execute WM_TIMER message when PostMessage

Tags: winapi, message-queue, message, postmessage

i am learning win32 thesedays
and playing with PostMessage function.

tricky thing i found was when posting WM_TIMER message into window message queue, window didn't receive any message.
if only receive when i set lparam to 0, otherwise not working at all
the code here.
and also i tested with sendmessage which is totally fine either ways.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            //PostMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 0, 0); // receive msg
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 0, 1); // not receiving
        }
        return 0;
        case WM_TIMER:
        {
            switch (wparam)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    HDC dc = GetDC(hWnd);

                    Ellipse(dc, 70, 70, 120, 120);
                    ReleaseDC(hWnd, dc);
                }
                break;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

would be amazing if somebody explain why this is happening.
just hope i am missing some basic concept of windows processing system.

Comment: Why are you posting `WM_TIMER` messages at all? You should be calling `SetTimer` and the system will post those messages to your window procedure.

Comment: It is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer), DispatchMessage() treats it differently and won't call WndProc.  Note that you *do* see this message in the message loop, after the GetMessage() call.  But that's where it ends, would be nice if it screamed bloody murder about the invalid function pointer.  It doesn't.

Comment: @HansPassant -- What's interesting is if you change it to `SendMessage`, it works fine. Just tried it out.

Comment: By design, SendMessage() directly calls WndProc so DispatchMessage() is not used.  GetMessage() only retrieves posted messages.  WM_TIMER is normally always posted, never sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`WM_TIMER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer) documentation:

> **lParam [in]**
>
> A pointer to an application-defined callback function that was passed to the `SetTimer` function when the timer was installed.

So, when you use `PostMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 0, 0)`, you pass 0 (as a null pointer) to `lParam`.

According to the [`SetTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer?redirectedfrom=MSDN) documentation:

> A pointer to the function to be notified when the time-out value elapses. For more information about the function, see TimerProc. **If `lpTimerFunc` is `NULL`, the system posts a WM_TIMER message to the application queue.** The `hwnd` member of the message's `MSG` structure contains the value of the `hWnd` parameter.

This means when `DispatchMessage()` sees the `WM_TIMER` message with its `lParam` set to 0, it will simply deliver the message as-is to the window message procedure of the window specified by `hWnd`.

But, when you use `PostMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 0, 1);` instead, you are passing 1 as the `lParam`, so it is treated as a pointer to a timer callback function.  This means when `DispatchMessage()` sees the `WM_TIMER` message with its `lParam` set to non-zero, it will not deliver the message to the window message procedure of `hWnd`, it will instead try to actually call the function pointed to by `lParam`, which is obviously illegal in this case. The system cannot call a function through this invalid pointer.

According to the [`DispatchMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage) documentation:

> The `MSG` structure must contain valid message values. If the `lpmsg` parameter points to a `WM_TIMER` message and the `lParam` parameter of the `WM_TIMER` message is not `NULL`, `lParam` points to a function that is called instead of the window procedure.

Comment: It's unclear how you arrived at the conclusion that it were impossible to post `WM_TIMER` messages. That's not what the quoted documentation says.

Comment: @IInspectable For my expression problem, I have modified the reply, anyway, I recommend using SetTimer.

Comment: Great. Now it doesn't answer the question that was asked anymore.

Comment: @IInspectable My mistakes for me wrongly read the question, I have revised my reply.

Comment: That's useless. It explains what someone that neither understands the message nor has access to the source code might guess. It's not like the system would see whether there is `WM_TIMER` in the queue, and if so read its arguments, and then decide where it gets delivered. You're going to have to ignore boatloads of facts to arrive at this conclusion.

Comment: `The system cannot handle the timer's timeout function through this pointer, so the WM_TIMER cannot be triggered.` [*citation needed*]

Comment: @Andy A non-null value in the lParam that isn't a function pointer fails to meet the API requirements and therefore triggers undefined behavior.